# how can I make an application stay in the foreground, I mean it can not be closed by the user? I'm using the PackageManager class

Tags: android-studio

I'm doing an application which serves as a control of some cameras, the problem is that I need that the user can not leave this app in any way, I need it is always in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

Use foreground Service component. [Here is the example.](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/)